# Can we have $ in spring bean id value?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

> bean id="terminal$containerManager" />

What is the meaning of $ in the bean id ?

Comment: i never used $ in bean id :)

Answer (score 0):

'$' is useful for bean **class** when you wish to refer to inner static class. For id it is pretty useless

```
<bean id="myBean" class="my.package.OuterClass$InnerClass">
```